# Swift: NSClassFromString and NSStringFromClass behave different for NSManagedObjects

Tags: swift, core-data, reflection

`NSStringFromClass` delivers fully qualified class names for class references like `<ClassName>".self"`

`NSStringClassFromString` delivers a class reference of kind `AnyClass` for fully qualified class names like `<AppId>"."<ClassName">`.

But it behaves different for subclasses of `NSManagedObject`.

Let's say the AppId is "MyApp".

```
class Foo: NSObject {}

@objc(Bar)
class Bar: NSManagedObject {}

print(NSStringFromClass(Foo.self))        // MyApp.Foo
print(NSStringFromClass(Bar.self))        // Bar

print(NSClassFromString("Foo"))           // nil
print(NSClassFromString("Bar"))           // MyApp.Bar
print(NSClassFromString("MyApp.Foo"))     // MyApp.Foo
print(NSClassFromString("MyApp.Bar"))     // nil
```

That can lead to problems, when creating the input for `NSClassFromString` dynamically, e.g. by concatenating the 'AppId' with the class name determined by `MyClass.self`. It seems that subclasses of `NSManagedObject` don't belong to the Apps namespace.

It's interesting. The functions are reversive.

```
let fco = NSClassFromString(NSStringFromClass(Foo.self))
let fct = NSClassFromString(NSStringFromClass(fco!))
// fco == fct    

let bco = NSClassFromString(NSStringFromClass(Bar.self))
let bct = NSClassFromString(NSStringFromClass(bco!))
// bco == bct
```

But the intermediate results differ, as you can see in the upper listing.

Serious question: Is this a bug or a feature? If it's a feature, what are the reasons and advantages.

Answer (score 0):

what i got from my Playground, and it differs from your results ...

```
import CoreData

class Foo: NSObject {
    required override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    let test = 100
}

@objc(Bar)
class Bar: NSManagedObject {
    required convenience init() {
        self.init(entity: NSEntityDescription(), insertIntoManagedObjectContext: nil)
    }
}

let s1 = NSStringFromClass(Foo.self) // "__lldb_expr_xxx.Foo"
let s2 = NSStringFromClass(Bar.self) // "Bar"

let cFooType = NSClassFromString(s1) as! Foo.Type
let c = cFooType.init()
c.test == 100 // true

// to create Bar, you have to implement a little bit more, but the
// strategy could be the same

// the init for class Bar is there just to compile, you need real values for entity an insertIntoManagedObjectContext ....
```